# Socket.io: Cannot emit data to specific room

Tags: node.js, swift, socket.io

I'm building a server socket in Node.js, the problem that I can't emit data to specific room. I have tried to print all socket-client id in room and it still print all socket id in that room normally.

```
function SocketManager(serverSocket, app) {
    let self = this;
    self.io = socket.listen(serverSocket);

    self.io.on('connection', function (client) {

        let user_id;

        client.on('join', function (userId) {
            user_id = userId;
            logger.info("SOCKET: User " + userId + " connected with id " + client.id);
            client.join(userId);
        });

        client.on('disconnect', function () {
            if (user_id)
                logger.info("SOCKET: User " + user_id + " disconnected with id " + client.id);
        });

        client.on('push_data', function (sensor_data) {
            let sensor_id = sensor_data.sensorId;
            app.models.sensor.findById(sensor_id).then(function (sensor) {
                let userId = sensor.createdBy;
                if (self.io.nsps["/"].adapter.rooms[userId]) {
                    Object.keys(self.io.nsps["/"].adapter.rooms[userId].sockets).forEach(function (socket) {
                        logger.info(socket);
                    });
                    self.io.in(userId).emit('pull_data', sensor_data);
                }
                // self.io.emit('pull_data', sensor_data);
            });
        });

    });
}
```

When I replace `self.io.in(userId).emit('pull_data', sensor_data)` 
with `self.io.emit('pull_data', sensor_data)`, client can receive data normally. Client side using Swift SocketIO.

Comment: Have you checked that that section of code is actually called, and the value of `userId`?

Comment: @jcaron I have checked, and it matches room id

Comment: I have created a basic project replicating your code and everything is fine, actually is emitting ok to the room created. What I would do is: I'd check if the userId has any space or misspelling? print out `userId` when is being used on the emit part and see if it matches with the roomId? Create a dummy room hard coded and see if you can emit to that room? anyways if you didn't solve it, give us more details like, which versions are you using of the libraries? maybe share your client code too and any logs that you would have.